# Is Junior Appian Developer a good entry level SWE position?

Tags: software-development, junior, computer-science

Just some background: I graduated with a dual degree in Mechanical Engineering and Computer Science. After grad I worked in the Mech Eng field for one year but now my contract has ended and I am sure that I want to transition towards comp sci/SWE. I have a handful of programming projects under my belt but no industry experience, so I am having a bit of trouble finding an entry level position.

My question is: I recently got an offer for an interview at a software consulting firm as a junior appian developer. Will this position help/or hurt my resume when I further want to apply for more advanced SWE jobs?

Any information would be helpful for me!

Thanks in advance!

PS - From what I understand reading online, Appian is a "low-code" automation platform

Comment: How does gaining experience hurt you?

Comment: I just want more clarity as to weather this particular experience would be beneficial to further Software related jobs or not? Like let's say after I work a year or two with this position, would HR look at my resume and just say "he has no ACTUAL software experience"

Comment: That's really going to depend on the subsequent job. If you're looking at another position developing with Appian, it'll look like great experience. If you're looking at a general position developing enterprise products, it'll look good (but not as good as using more standardised tools). If you're looking at an unrelated development position like writing mobile games, then it'll be almost useless. The question HR will look at isn't "does he have _actual_ software experience", but "does he have experience relevant to this role".

Comment: Is this a joke?

Comment: Why do you think it's a joke? It seems a genuine question to me.

Comment: This would seem to just be a wind-up or joke.  "Appian" is not software.

Comment: It's not a joke. Im being serious. On the application it said "Bachelors degree in computer science or engineering". But it doesnt seem like it haha

Comment: hi @cooldecola  if this is a windup, funny.  If it's not a windup - I just don't know how clear anyone can be:  **forget about this.  It is career suicide.**  The fact that you ever "worked" on "Appian" will mean you'll never get a job as a programmer.  Do not take this job.  It is so silly it's just funny.  Pls, forget about it and move on to the 100,000 other jobs on offer!  It's hard to get that "first job" but this is not it.  Best of luck.

Comment: *"I graduated with a dual degree in Mechanical Engineering and Computer Science"*  Jesu dude you have the DREAM DEGREE.  You'll be making a zillion bucks with a few years.  If (for some incredible reason) you took this job, you will have to KEEP IT A SECRET the rest of your life.  It's silly, risible!  Move on and enjoy, best of luck - not that you need it with that degree.

Answer (score 5):

**Probably hurts if you want to write code**

I don't have any direct experience with Appian, but from what I understand it is basically drag and drop software engineering, i.e you are taking a lot of pre-built blocks and ordering them in a process flow to get a particular result. [You can see a demo of it here.](https://youtu.be/Sk6HuQ_klxY?t=274) Appian describes it as using Lego blocks to build an application.

From that video and the "lego blocks" description, I would not consider Appian development to be the same kind of software dev at all. It seems like it strips away a lot of key concepts that are in standard code software development like architecture, networks, git, figuring out how to connect two blocks that don't have a clear connector, etc.

I do not hire, but that is quite different from what I do as a developer.

Comment: _.".but from what I understand it is basically drag and drop software engineering"_ Correct. Back in days there was DreamWeaver - now there's Appian.. ;)

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't even think this was a 'real' developer role